# Why there is no any standard Gateway Interface for languages C and/or C++ as WSGI for Python?

Tags: c++, python, c, web-applications, wsgi

Or is there any? I would be happy to know if any.

Thank you.

Comment: it may also have to do with compiled vs interpreted ...

Comment: What do you expect it to provide, exactly?  CGI is pretty easy to do with C.  There are CGI libraries available, but it's easy enough to do with just the standard runtime as well..

Comment: @Dmitri: the purpose of WSGI (and Rack and PSGI and others) is to be agnostic of a particular connection mechanism.  They all allow the application to be connected to the web server via multiple protocols (CGI, FastCGI, SCGI) as well as a web server's native API without changing the application code.

Comment: @AndréCaron: If you write in C for plain old CGI, you can often change among major operating systems and web servers with no (CGI related) source code changes already.  There may be times when you'd want to use something else, for extra features or performance, but there's often no compelling reason to... which is why I ask what the OP expects from the interface.

Comment: @NicolBolas, well thank you very much!!!!
I was asking the question because I was wondering the technical difficulties, or if it was not the case any ongoing or available  project for this!

Comment: @JoranBeasley, that couldn't be the case, as I might add the Python itself is a hybrid language in respect of interpreter/compiler

Comment: @Dmitri, I suspect websites with a very high overload really need a huge improvement in their processing times. Consider that it would be very cost-effective. You could answer requests of 3 servers on 2! So I really doubt your approach!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISAPI on Windows/IIS. NSAPI is supported by a number of vendors.

Answer (score 0):

The closest to a gateway standard for C/C++ would be [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/). Otherwise modules for specific web servers is the norm.